# jump to millis not working on youtube-api

Tags: android, youtube-api

I have learned to make a player from youtube-API on https://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-youtube-api-to-embed-video-in-an-android-app/

I get an error when the practice jumps to a certain second

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.seekToMillis(int)' on a null object reference

and this is my coding

```
public class SitepointSample extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
private YouTubePlayerView youtubeView;

private MyPlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener;
private MyPlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener;

private YouTubePlayer player;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_sitepoint_sample);

final EditText seekToText = (EditText)   findViewById(R.id.seek_to_text);
Button seekToButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seek_to_button);
seekToButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    int skipToSecs = Integer.valueOf(seekToText.getText().toString());
    player.seekToMillis(skipToSecs * 1);
  }
});

playbackEventListener = new MyPlaybackEventListener();
playerStateChangeListener = new MyPlayerStateChangeListener();

youtubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
youtubeView.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer,
                                  boolean wasRestored) {
this.player = player;
if (!wasRestored) {
  youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
  youTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);
  youTubePlayer
      .cueVideo("fhWaJi1Hsfo"); //plays video_id == https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo
}
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                  YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
  errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
} else {
  String error = String.format(getString(R.string.player_error), errorReason.toString());
  Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST) {
  // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
  youtubeView.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
}
}

protected YouTubePlayerView getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
return youtubeView;
}

private void showMessage(String message) {
Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Can anyone handle this?

Comment: when you click the button ,that time video is playing or not?

Answer (score 0):

Please give a try to this code :

```
PlayFragment(start, stop){
player.seekTo(40);

while(player.getCurrentTime() !> 60)
{
     sleep(1000);
}

player.stop();
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where should I apply that code?
I've tried with that code but the code does not run properly.